# Why does this string comparison does not work?

Tags: string, delphi, comparison

i got this partial code:

```
var  
  MYOBCardId, WSCustCode, ExCode, 
  Destination, IncomeStream, MyobSalesAc: String;

IncomeStream := VarToStr(Trim(SheetData.Cells[7, StrRow]));
MyobSalesAc := '';
if IncomeStream = '840 DRUG-temp controlled' then 
  MyobSalesAc := '42400';
if AnsiCompareStr(IncomeStream,'900 Industrial') = 0 then 
  MyobSalesAc := '41200';
if IncomeStream = '950 Live Animals' then 
  MyobSalesAc := '41800';
```

the thing is IF then statement does not seem to work. If the value of IncomeStream is '900 Industrial' (examined via debugger), MYOBSalesAc will be '' instead '41200'.
the comparison does not work at all. Its same for all the values. Using the AnsiComparestr does not give the correct results.

any pointers?

regards
rashid

Comment: `IncomeStream` is not what you say it is. `AnsiCompareStr` is known to work correctly.

Comment: i tried using IncomeStream = '900 Industrial' where IncomeStream = '900 Industrial'. The result is false when it should be true.

Comment: The `=` operator is also known to work correctly.

Comment: Not sure why you Trim() and do VarToStr() on the result since Trim() should take and return a string. What type does SheetData.Cells contain?

Comment: could the source of the variable : VarToStr(Trim(SheetData.Cells[7,StrRow])) be the issue. SheetData is a stringgrid.

Comment: it contains the values ''900 Industrial' for example. From visual inspection and debugger, it strings should match but its not happening. very strange. the Trim and vartostr is to get rid of trailing spaces and conver to string. i assume the stringgrid stores variables as variant.

Comment: just a side note: you should really use `Trim(VarToStr(SheetData.Cells[7, StrRow]))` in case the cell is null. not `VarToStr(Trim(...` because `VarToStr` in that case is pointless.

Comment: Are you try using SameStr or SameText?

Comment: If I hit such a problem, I'd be dumping the strings out, codepoint by codepoint to find the character that doesn't match, and its ordinal values.

Answer (score 4):

`AnsiCompareStr`, the equals comparison operator `=` are all known to work correctly. Thus we can only conclude that `IncomeStream` does not hold the value `'900 Industrial'`. The most obvious possibility is that the space is in fact some other form of whitespace. Perhaps a tab character. Or perhaps a non-breaking space. Or perhaps it is two spaces.

Take a look at the binary representation of the two strings and compare them.

Comment: thanks david, but you loss me there at binary representation. any sample code? thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the value of `ord(IncomeStream[4])` in the debugger. If it was a space then it would be 32.

Comment: it return a 32. thus a need to remove the white space. thanks.

Comment: Well, no. The string you are comparing against has a space in character 4 also. You are looking for differences. Check that the two strings have the same ordinal value for each character, and that they have the same length.

Comment: No, @User, that's not the correct conclusion. The fourth character is *supposed* to be a space. What you've confirmed is that *that* character is correct. Don't remove it. The difference in the strings is somewhere else. Use the debugger to find out where.

Comment: Or write a string comparison function. Always fun to return to the basics sometimes, and do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For text comparison of this kind, better use AnsiSameText. AnsiSameText will do a case-insensitive comparison. For case sensitive comparison, use AnsiSameStr instead. If you are using D2009 or above, you must use SameText and SameStr.

Comment: Sadly CHristopher you are  wrong.  Ansi in the name of a function SHOULD in a sane world, mean it's a function for Ansi Strings only, but for various historical reasons, it does NOT mean that in Delphi. Read the docs carefully, and observe the chaos.

Comment: On Delphi's prior to 2009, SameText and SameStr does not work with no ASCII [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) chars. Try this code on Delphi7: "if SameText('español', 'ESPAÑOL')..." and you will undertand whay I say.

Comment: Your argument that we "must" use SameText in Delphi 2009 and above is that in prior versions, SameText didn't work the way some people expected for non-ASCII characters. That's a bogus argument. "You must use it now because it was broken before." Furthermore, you're missing the point by recommending different functions here. With our eyes, we can plainly see that the two strings in question should match with AnsiCompareStr; *case* is clearly not the problem, so a non-case-sensitive function won't fix anything.

Comment: @WarrenP, you are wrong, Ansi prefix denotes locale support, not a string type.

Comment: @Rob, you loose unicode support using AnsiCompareStr on Delphi >= 2009, so we must, or at leat should use CompareStr on D2009. I preffer using AnsiCompareStr for what it is intended, sorting list. For text visual or lexical comparison, use SameText and similars.

Comment: That's not what Warren said, @User. He said that in a "sane" world, the "Ansi" prefix *would* refer to AnsiString, but then he said that's *not* what it means in Delphi.

Comment: @RobKen, nope, i do not agree. This links two wholly different concepts together. Not very *sane*.

Comment: As I understand, on Delphi <= 2009, String is the same as AnsiString. On D2009 and above, String is something similar as the old Widestrings

Comment: userX: Then they should have called it `LocaleAwareSameText` however they named it long before the Unicode transition. Thus the confusion. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To find out where the difference lies, use your own comparison function. Go character by character, until you find what looks the same to your eyes, but is different by ordinal value.

Other people suggested using the debugger, but if you can't do that, then write code.

```
function CompareStrExt(s1,s2:String; var idx:Integer; var c1,c2:Char):Boolean;
var
 len1,len2,minlen:Integer;
begin
    result := true;
    c1 := Chr(0);
    c2 := Chr(0);
    idx := 1;
    len1 := Length(s1);
    len2 := Length(s2);
    minlen := len1;
    if len2<minlen then
        minlen := len2;
    while idx <= minlen do begin
        c1 := s1[idx];
        c2 := s2[idx];
        if c1<>c2 then begin
            result := false;
            exit;
        end;
        Inc(idx);
    end;
    if idx>len1 then
         c1 := Chr(0)
    else
        c1 := s1[idx];

    if idx>len2 then
        c2 := Chr(0)
    else
        c2 := s2[idx];

    result := (len1=len2);



end;
```

Here's a sample call:

```
  if not CompareStrExt('123','123a',idx,c1,c2) then begin
      // make ordinal Numeric (binary) values visible to your eyeballs.
      msg := IntToStr(Ord(c1)) + ' <> ' + IntToStr(Ord(c2)); 
  end;
```